# Does model.getProperty() return a live object for objects that are members of an array?

Tags: sapui5

I get an object from within an array in my model (a JSONmodel type) which is

```
{
    "task": [
      {
        "dbid": 465,
        "bk_cnt": 11,
    }, {
        "dbid": 472,
        "bk_cnt": 16,
    }
            ]
}
```

I bind this model to a table and connect the bk_cnt up to an objectNumber in a cell. No problem so far.

In code I want to change the value of the first bk_cnt value from 11 to 20 on press of a button. Inside the event I have:

```
        var model = this.getView().getModel() // get the model
        var tasks = model.getProperty("/task"); // get as a JS object
        tasks[0].bk_cnt = 20  // update the model...will it update the view?
        // model.refresh()    // it will if this is uncommented.
```

Problem: Though it is bound to the view, the displayed value of bk_cnt does not change. if I add model.refresh() it does. This code is extracted from a larger section and one of the larger features is sorting by column click. When I click a column to re-sort (no change to the model), the value 20 appears.

What gives?

Musings: I have read that the model.getProprty() function returns a javascript object with a live reference back to the model, and that a change to the value of the object will automatically be reflected in the view for any bound controls. Does this statement fall down on array attributes ?

EDIT: Still feeling around the issue I find that

```
model.setProperty("/task/0/bk_cnt", 20)
```

Does not require a model.refresh() to update the view. Not a total surprise as this command is directly acting through the model. This leaves me thinking that the 'live' object returned by getProperty() is only live when it is a primitive datatype like a string or integer, but not for a JS object. Or am I missing something ?

EDIT 2: @Ash points out in his answer that there is a further approach which is to access the JS object from the model property, set whatever attributes need to be updated in the JS object, then replace that into the model, e.g.

```
var tasks = model.getProperty("/task");
tasks[0].bk_cnt = 20
model.setProperty('/task', tasks)
```

Second edit done to complete the trio of approaches for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model object is an abstraction layer ON TOP of a javascript object. There is no way that a change within an object is notified anywhere. You need to explicitly trigger the notifications through model.refresh() or model.setProperty().

So both of your solutions are valid, another one (which I favor) would be

```
var tasks = model.getProperty("/task");
tasks[0].bk_cnt = 20
model.setProperty('/task', tasks)
```

But this actually depends on how you bind your model to your UI objects :)

Comment: How do I bind my model to the UI objects? I am using a table in this case and it is defined in an XML view with the attribute 'items' set to `{path: '/task'}`. Is there another way to bind?

Comment: You can use {/task} and omit path unless you do not have additional parameters. Of course you can bind programmatically.

Comment: `model.refresh()` will refresh all bindings of that model. Refresh a binding means that the controls are updated with the current values of the Javascript object in the model. `model.setProperty()` will of course change the Javascript object in the model and the update all bindings with the same path or a subpath. You have to consider that for performance reasons: If only the data of one row changes you do not have to refresh all rows.